# How to show only data that have balance in Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports

Sorry for my bad English.
I have some question.
i have data like this.

Invoice No | Type | Charges | Credits
1          | INV  | 10      | 0
1          | Cash | 0       | -10
2          | INV  | 20      | 0
3          | INV  | 20      | 0
3          | Cash | 0       | -10

And i want to show on report like this

Invoice No | Type | Charges | Credits
2          | INV  | 20      | 0
3          | INV  | 10      | 0

So, if the balance is zero then data not show.

How i can do that?

---

Comment: where are you data come from?

Comment: Your original data and the result you want are not the same. Please revise your post so it is more clear what you want. You also need to tell us which column -- charges or credits -- that you want to exclude when the balance is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry make u confuse.
But i have already found the answer.
i have data from table Account Receivable (AR).
i have 2 group, first based on customer and the second based on invoice number
i place the data in group footer (invoice number).
i created a formula `@Charges`

```
Sum({AR.CHARGES}, {AR.INVOICE}) + sum({AR.CREDITS}, {AR.INVOICE})
```

and create suppress formula in group footer section (invoice number)

```
{@charges) = 0
```

Thanks :)